# Does the following work as a proof for the intermediate value theorum?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

$f$ is a continuous function on $(a,b)$.

CLAIM: There exists an element $x$ in the domain of f such that $f(x)=L$, and $f(a) \le L \le f(b)$

Proof:
for every $\epsilon> 0$, there exists $\delta> 0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$

Let $c$ be an element in the domain of $f$, between $a$ and $b$, s.t. $c=\sup\{ x:f(x)< L\}$

let $x$ be in the $\delta$ neighborhood of $c$, which implies $f(x)$ is in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(c)$ ie. $f(c)- \epsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \epsilon$

Now, assume $f(c)\neq L$. first, assume $f(c)> L$. 
let $\epsilon = L- f(c)$, now plugging this into the inequality yields $f(c) < L$, a contradiction.
Now assume that $f(c) < L$. let $\epsilon= f(c)- L$. plugging this into the inequality yields $L < f(c)$, which is a contradiction.

therefore, $f(c)= L$, which proves the intermediate value theorem

is this a valid proof?

Comment: The "Claim" is not a correct statement of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @JonasMeyer why?

Comment: If $f (c)>L $ then $L-f (c)<0 <\epsilon $, so $\epsilon \neq L-f (c) $ which is why you can't plug in $L-f (c) $ for $\epsilon $ . The analogous statement is true in the case $L>f (c) $.

Comment: My main problem with the CLAIM (besides it is not stating the IVT) is that it is meaningless. The function is only defined on $(a,b)$. How can $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ even make sense? The function is *not defined* in these points.

Answer (score 1):

No it has some issues.

There are a few details that need to be improved. First you need to formulate the IVT correctly. First it requires $f$ to be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Also the theorem states that $x$ would be within $[a,b]$ (if we want it to be in the inner of the interval we need to restrict $L$ to $f(a)<L<f(b)$ instead).

And obviously that you've not included these will spot details in the proof that needs improvement (obviously we need to use these prerequisites because we can find counter examples if we drop them).

Actually it starts with the claim that $c$ is in the domain of $f$ which wouldn't follow. Actually the construct needs to be improved a bit, but also use that $f$ is continuous on the closed interval (implying it's defined there). We need to make sure that the set is both non-empty and bounded above, but also that $b$ is a upper bound and $a$ isn't (unless $a\in U_L$). We do this by restricting the set to $[a,b]$ that is the set being $U_L = \{x\in[a,b]: f(x)<L\}$. It's obviously bounded above and $b$ is an upper bound. To show that it's non-empty we would like to require $f(a)<L<f(b)$ in which case $a\in U_L$ (the case where $f(a)=L$ we obviously have that $x=a$ makes $f(x)=L$). We now see that $a\le c=\sup U_L\le b$.

Then as for the value of $f(c)$ you will have to be more careful. If $f(c)>L$ then $L-f(c)<0$ which makes that value no good for a value of $\epsilon$ in the definition of continuity. Instead if $f(c)>L$ you use for example $\epsilon=(f(c)-L)/2$, then for any $x>c-\delta$ we would have $f(x)>L$ which means that there are no members in $U_L$ between $c-\delta$ and $c$ which contradicts the assumption that $c$ is the least upper bound. Conversely if $f(c)<L$ we use the same method to show that if $x<c+\delta$ then $f(x)<L$ which makes $c$ not an upper bound at all.

A detail however to watch out for is the possibility that $c$ is at one of the endpoints of the interval. For example if $c=b$ we can't use the above to get an contradiction if $f(c)<L$ or to prove that $f(c)\ge L$, but then we use the prerequisite that $f(c)=f(b)\ge L\ge f(a)$. The other part of the proof works, ie getting a contradiction if $f(c)>L$ which is where we use that the function is actually continuous on the closed interval.